# How to set values in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: nsuserdefaults, setvalue

I have this:

NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [responseString objectFromJSONString];

```
        NSLog(@"%@" , [responseDict objectForKey:@"loginid"]);
```

and i want to put my "loginid" to NSUserDefault..

how to put the loginid value to NSUserDefault, and Retrieve ?

i tried this way but not working properly

[defaults setInteger:[responseDict objectForKey:@"loginid"] forKey:@"user_id"];

Please need help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To put in **NSUserDefaults** you can do this

For saving:

```
NSString *logInId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[responseDict objectForKey:@"loginid"]];
NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
[preferences setValue:logInId forKey:@"logInId"];
[preferences synchronize];
```

For retrieving:

```
NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
NSString *logInIdValue = [preferences valueForKey:@"logInId"];
```